# what s the difference between ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED and compress only in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, compression, oracle12c

I have created a simple two tables in Oracle 12c and how do inspect their difference in compression and performance difference???

```
create table t1 ( c1 number, c2 varchar2(1) ) compress basic ;


create table t2 ( c1 number, c2 varchar2(1) )  ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED;
```

Answer (score 0):

The significant difference is that when the advanced compression is used, you can add/change data through DML operations without having to uncompress the data fist.
An extract from the Oracle Advanced Compression white sheet for 12c:

> "The benefits of Advanced Row Compression go beyond just on-disk
> storage savings. One significant advantage is Oracle’s ability to read
> compressed blocks (data and indexes) directly, in memory, without
> uncompressing the blocks."